# Sending email that won't be threaded by Google Inbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, basecamp

We are sending login link for user via email (like Basecamp). The email is of the same title ("Login to our website") and similar content so Google Inbox will try to group them into a thread, make it hard for user to click on the later link.

We noticed that login link from Basecamp is not getting grouped like that. So if you requested to login from Basecamp 2 times, you see two emails not a grouped one.

How could we do like Basecamp? Or someone at Google inject a special code for Basecamp?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the From: field, either just by name or also the sending email address; that way the email won't get grouped. For instance, no-reply@yourdomain.com and email credentials under admin@yourdomain.com.

Comment: That is a nice trick. Though I'm pertty sure that Basecamp use the same From field but the email is not grouped, which is what I am after.

Comment: You should investigate Basecamps email closely, look at the email header and compair it with your emails, you should for sure find a small detail that is different. I never heard of Basecamp, so I can't help you with looking at their email, but it shouldn't be hard to find out, unless there's no possibility in Gmail to view email headers.